# Iphone popup alert message

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can't find this anywhere. I don't want to have to use the debugger everytime. How do I get print messages on the iphone.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the NSLog function:

```
NSLog(@"Your message here.");
// with parameters:
NSString * myParam = @"Some value";
NSLog(@"myParam:%@", myParam);
```

The messages get written to the console log.  You can view them in the simulator by running Console.app or by switching XCode to the Debugger/Console view `(XCode -> Run -> Console)`

If you really want to do a popup alert (like the javascript `alert()` function) you can do :

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test Message" 
                                                  message:@"This is a sample"
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: FYI UIAlertView is now deprecated with iOS 8.

Comment: example of how to replace `UIAlertView` with new `UIAlertController ` one can find here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html

Comment: or in official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> // open a alert with an OK and cancel button
> UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView"
>         message:@"My message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
>         otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
> [alert show];
> [alert release];
> ```

Sample images:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
UIAlertView* alert;
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"Much more info" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for `UIAlertView` with either Google or the Xcode Documentation Viewer.